# BreezeJS does not perform filtering in database?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata, breeze

I am using the following query on the  client:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("AllCustomers").where("CustomerId,"==",criteriaValue);
return this.manager.executeQuery(query)
```

which results in the following URL:
`/breeze/myAPI/AllCustomers?$filter=CustomerId%20eq%2012`

I have noticed that the filtering is not performed in the database (there is no WHERE statemenet in dthe SQL executed by the database). I suspect, that the reason for this is `Breeze.WebApi.QueryHelper.WrapResult`, which calls `Enumerable.ToList`. The later converts IQueriable to list which forces execution of the query before if is filtered by default Microsoft OData implementation:

```
// if a select or expand was encountered we need to
// execute the DbQueries here, so that any exceptions thrown can be properly returned.
// if we wait to have the query executed within the serializer, some exceptions will not
// serialize properly.
queryResult = Enumerable.ToList((dynamic)queryResult);
queryResult = PostExecuteQuery((IEnumerable)queryResult);
```

Is this a bug in Breeze or am I doing something wrong?

I am using Oracle ODP.NET provider for entity framework.

UPDATE: I am using WebAPI and the controller method quite simple:

```
[BreezeController]
public class MyController : ApiController
{

[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Customer> AllCustomers()
{            
  return  _contextProvider.Context.Customers;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was a bug and has been fixed.  The fix will be available in our next full tested release (v 1.4.3 ) or you can get our current dev version now from the Breeze Git repository.

Note that this issue only happens with a badly constructed filter against a query that involves a "named query" on the server and where the client DOES NOT have an entityType/resource name mapping for the queried resource.  In the condition where the Breeze client DOES have an entityType/resourceName mapping any invalid filter will throw a client side error before even going to the server.

and... Thanks for reporting it. :)

Comment: Thanks. What's the commit of the fix? https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/commit/c94b20d5141c72b8295b179b93638a70670133f6 ?

Comment: Just take the latest, we try to insure that it always builds cleanly. Note that it will still be labelled 1.4.2 until we release.

Comment: I understand this. I am just being curious, what the fix was, because I was unable to fix it by myself :-)

Comment: Ah, ok. Take a look at c94b20d5141c72b8295b179b93638a70670133f6. The fix was to add an if (!actionExecutedContext.Response.IsSuccessStatusCode) call to the BreezeQueryableAttribute.

Answer (score 0):

In general the filter criteria would be applied on the data tier in the SQL query.

The code fragment that you cite ... the one that appears to force a premature execution of the query such that it retrieves the entire table ... would seem to come into play only if your client query performs a select or expand. I'm not seeing a select or expand in your query. What makes you think that Breeze.WebAPI is following this particular code path in your case? Are you neglecting to tell us something about your implementation of the "AllCustomers" Web API method?

Comment: Because I have  traced it to this location with the debugger. It is called from BreezeQueryableAttribute.OnActionExecuted.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough. As the code clearly states, it thinks you are performing a select or expand which is not evident in the client request. Moreover, Breeze would have added the filter criteria to the query PRIOR to the executing that query. You are describing behavior we have never seen in a properly formed server method. We really need to see the controller class definition (Web API, right? You can omit the methods other than "AllCustomers"), the "AllCustomers" method including its attributes, and any code between that method and the way back to the data context.

Comment: While trying to reproduce the problem in simplified scenario I have found that unfiltered SQL is executed if the filter contains invalid field name. In this case, the whole table is selected, converted ToList() and then HTTP 400 bad request is returned. The offending WrapResult method code fragement is executed even if the filter contains a valid field name, but in this case the ObjectQuery passed in queryResult parameter of WrapResult method correctly contains WHERE expression. So, Breeze shouldn't call ToList for invalid requests.

Comment: An interesting finding!  If I understand correctly, the client posed a query with filter referencing an invalid field name ... and the Web API method simply ignored the filter altogether, causing the entire table to be returned? That's not nice. Normally BreezeJS blocks queries with invalid field references. Regardless, the Web API query should not execute at all if any part of it is invalid. This is a security issue! We are delegating to the Web API for this part. I wonder why they let this through? Thanks for the clues in any case.

Comment: You correctly understood the first part (client sends the invalid filter), but not the second part.  What happens with BreezeController is the following: 1) unfiltered SQL is executed  - the whole table is read into memory, 2) HTTP 400 is returned to the client (the content of the table is NOT returned). What happens with the default ApiController is just 2). So it is not a problem on the WebApi part, but with the Breeze. The ApiController does not execute the query, but the BreezeController does. You shouldn't try to WrapResults if the results will not be returned due to HTTP 400 bad request.

Answer (score 0):

Matra,

We were not able to reproduce this problem.

If I execute a valid query:

```
    var query = new breeze.EntityQuery()
        .from("Employees")
        .where("employeeID","==", 1);
```

The proper SQL is created as I can see in the Profiler:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[EmployeeID] AS [EmployeeID], 
[Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
[Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
[Extent1].[TitleOfCourtesy] AS [TitleOfCourtesy], 
[Extent1].[BirthDate] AS [BirthDate], 
[Extent1].[HireDate] AS [HireDate], 
[Extent1].[Address] AS [Address], 
[Extent1].[City] AS [City], 
[Extent1].[Region] AS [Region], 
[Extent1].[PostalCode] AS [PostalCode], 
[Extent1].[Country] AS [Country], 
[Extent1].[HomePhone] AS [HomePhone], 
[Extent1].[Extension] AS [Extension], 
[Extent1].[Photo] AS [Photo], 
[Extent1].[Notes] AS [Notes], 
[Extent1].[PhotoPath] AS [PhotoPath], 
[Extent1].[ReportsToEmployeeID] AS [ReportsToEmployeeID], 
[Extent1].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion], 
[Extent1].[FullName] AS [FullName]
FROM [dbo].[Employee] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[EmployeeID] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=1
```

However, if I execute the query with an invalid field:

```
    var query = new breeze.EntityQuery()
        .from("Employees")
        .where("invalidEmployeeID","==", 1);
```

the query doesn’t even make it to the DB, as expected.
Can you provide a small sample reproducing the problem, so we can investigate further?

Comment: I am using a rather non-standard set up: Oracle Entity Framework provider chained with the Tracing provider, so small sample might be hard to provide. I can see that the tracing provider logs beginning and end of the execution of the query (without WHERE part). When the database is hit, the calls stacks looks like this: `Breeze.WebApi.QueryHelper.WrapResult(..) Line 231, Breeze.WebApi.dll!Breeze.WebApi.BreezeQueryableAttribute.OnActionExecuted(..)  Line 88`. The offending line is `queryResult = Enumerable.ToList((dynamic)queryResult)`. Did you hit this line during the tests?